# Create directory for configuration when running cargo install

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I built a tool that requires configuration by means of a `config.yaml`. I'd like to provide a basic version of that file along with the installation. Is it possible to have customizable task carried out (such as creating a directory under `/etc/mytool/` and creating a file herein) when running `cargo install --path .`?

Comment: `build.rs` file?

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about that. I'll fumble something together and post it here once I have a working solution. Thanks @ChayimFriedman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Build Scripts](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#build-scripts) are your friend.

The Rust file designated by the `build` command (relative to the package root) will be compiled and invoked before anything else is compiled in the package, allowing your Rust code to depend on the built or generated artifacts. By default Cargo looks up for "build.rs" file in a package root (even if you do not specify a value for build).

Use `build = "custom_build_name.rs"` to specify a custom build name, e.g. add in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
# ...
build = "custom_build_name.rs"
```

Comment: `build.rs` is the default, not need to specify it IIRC.

Comment: Yes, didn't need that. Still, works like a charm. Thanks @Carlos!

Comment: I edited my reply. You don't need to specify the file as it is the default; I meant to write `custom_build_name.rs`. Thanks for heads up!